# Interpreting Spark plans

Tags: apache-spark

```
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
'Aggregate ['dest_country_name], [unresolvedalias('dest_country_name, None), count(1) AS count#20L]
+- Relation[DEST_COUNTRY_NAME#10,ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME#11,count#12] csv
```

What do the column name + literal "#" + number mean? For example, `DEST_COUNTRY_NAME#10` and `count#20L`. I can't find documentation on this.

Answer (score 2):

Number added after "#" is auto-generated by Spark. It was designed for columns which are generated by Spark to make it easier to keep everything in order. I see two main befefits:

- Spark is mitigating names conflicts because count#1 is not the same column as count#2
- Numbers are representing order in which columns are computed, so Spark knows that it should first calculate count#1 and then count#2 which may be helpful if both computations are connected to each other

Comment: So if I see count#2 in addition to count#1, then they are columns from different tables?

Comment: You may have two counts calculated on single table so you can't assume that they are from other tables